# Reinstalling windows 8

Tags: windows, ubuntu, installation, uninstall

I completely removed windows 8 and installed ubuntu mate on my laptop now I want to reinstall win 8. I have recovery on usb but noting in ubuntu will boot to usb, i have kali on another usb and that will not boot too. I want to have win 8 and kali but cant get anything to boot off usb. my bios is set to usb the is not hdd usb option, legacy is off its on uefi off secure boot, it sees the usb drives . not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your USB devices are not bootable (that is, they contain no bootloader code). This is usually pretty easy to solve, but you'll need a Windows computer for the best chance at success.

1. First, attach the Windows recovery flashdrive to a Windows machine on which you can run a program as Admin (technically this shouldn't need admin but the utility might demand it anyhow).
2. In an admin command prompt (CMD or Powershell) run `diskpart`.
3. Use the `list disk` and `select disk` commands to select the first flashdrive, then use `list partition` and `select partition` to select the relevant partition on the drive (there's probably only one).
4. Use the command `active` to mark the partition as bootable. This will tell the BIOS/EFI that it can find a Windows bootloader here, which will then start the installer/recovery program.
5. `Exit` diskpart and safely remove the flashdrive. Put it back in the computer you're trying to reinstall Windows on, and try booting from the flashdrive again.

If that doesn't work, then there's a slightly more complicated and time-consuming process that sometimes works when the first one fails:

1. As before, put the flashdrive in a Windows machine where you can run commands as Admin.
2. Back up the flashdrive by copying all the files off of it to folder on another drive (probably the hard disk). **Make sure you get all the files, including Hidden and System ones!**
3. In an admin terminal, run `diskpart` (as above).
4. Use `list disk`, `select disk`, `list partition`, `select partition` as above.
5. Run `delete partition` to remove the partition entirely. **This will permanently delete any data you didn't back up!**
6. Run `create partition primary` to create a new, empty partition that fills the selected disk (the flashdrive).
7. Run `list partition` and `select partition` again to ensure the new partition is selected.
8. Run `active` to mark the new partition as bootable.
9. Run `format fs=FAT32 quick` to format the flashdrive with the maximally-compatible FAT32 filesystem.
10. `Exit` out of diskpart.
11. Copy the files you backed up - your recovery image, which hopefully has the necessary bootable files - back onto the flashdrive (it should have appeared, possibly under a new drive letter, when it was formatted).
12. Safely remove the flashdrive and plug it into your computer again.
13. Try to boot off the flashdrive again. It will hopefully work this time.